# How can I retrieve all rows and columns from a table in a mySql database?

Tags: mysql, http, go, go-gin

For all of my `GET` requests, I'm getting an `Internal Server Error 500`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, so maybe there's something that I don't understand or am looking over and need a second pair of eyes. Any help/hints are appreciated. My code is below:

```
/**
 *  Return all Users and their respective rows from users table
 **/
func (user *User) GetAll() ([]User, *errors.RestErr) {
    var (
        currUser User
        users    []User
    )

//queryGetAllUsers = "select id, first_name, last_name, email, username, password, created_on, updated_on FROM users;
    rows, err := users_db.Client.Query(queryGetAllUsers)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.NewInternalServerError(err.Error())
    }

    // loop through addresses of users returned from database and append column values to collection
    for rows.Next() {
        if err := rows.Scan(&user.ID, &user.FirstName, &user.LastName, &user.Email, &user.Username, &user.Password, &user.CreatedOn, &user.UpdatedOn); err != nil {
            return nil, mysql_utils.ParseError(err)
        }
        users = append(users, currUser)
    }

    defer rows.Close()
    if len(users) == 0 {
        return nil, errors.NewNotFoundError("No users in table")
    }
    return users, nil
}
```

Comment: This is unrelated but you're using `defer` wrong, `defer` should be used **before** you're done with whatever you need to release, **not after**. That is: `defer rows.Close()` should be used immediately after the first error check, not after the for loop, otherwise you're setting yourself up for bugs.

Comment: The `500` error, given the code in the question, seems to be returned by the `Query` method and if that is indeed the case you should share the content of the `queryGetAllUsers` string, it is highly likely that the SQL syntax in that string is invalid, or you're referencing non-existent tables/columns/etc. or it's also possible that you're actually not connected to the db even though you might you think you are...

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks for the insight and comment. The database is definitely connected. My `POST` requests work fine. Somehow, when I edited this post, the comment got deleted, but I just included the value of `queryGetAllUsers`. I've compared the columns that I'm referencing multiple times thinking that I might've looked over something very minor. And I forgot to copy over the closing quotation mark, so that's good, too.